# Reboot CentOS 5 server with SNMP script

Tags: linux, bash, kvm, centos5

Trying to use a bash script to reboot a CentOS 5.10 server via a SNMP call.

- I am able to connect via SNMP to the server.
- Running OnApp 3.2 HV on the server with KVM.
- Upgraded from 5.7 to 5.10 in attempt to get the newest possible
  packages without resorting to 6.x
- SysRq is enabled /boot/config-2.6.18-371.9.1.el5
  (CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ=y)
- Tried enabling kernel.sysrq = 1 in /etc/sysctl.conf
- Tried enabling inside the script: echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
- Hangs with the root events/0 with too many threads.

The basics of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

logger -p local5.debug -i -- `basename $0` $@

# Remove lock file before reboot
rm -f /onapp/reboot.lk

# Will attempt to sync all mounted filesystems.
echo s > /proc/sysrq-trigger
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do

    if dmesg | grep "Emergency Sync complete" > /dev/null; then
            break
    else
            sleep 1
    fi
done

# Remount all FS to RO
# Will attempt to remount all mounted filesystems read-only.
echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do

    if dmesg | grep "Emergency Remount complete" > /dev/null; then
            break
    else
            sleep 1
    fi

done

# Reboot server
echo "Rebooting"
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger

exit 0
```

If this isn't the way to do this on CentOS 5 then an alternative way via SNMP would be wonderful.  It works with a Zen server on centos 5.7 but then KVM is kernel based...  The jump to CentOS 6 isn't an "in-place" upgrade so migrating all the VMs would be murder.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just run /sbin/rebbot ?

Comment: Its very important to sync the disks first as virtual machines are linked to external storage.  That is why the script waits so long.

Comment: /sbin/reboot will sync the disks, part of the reboot procedure is to unmount all file systems.

Comment: True. I will try /sbin/reboot.  I was thinking that mounting the disks back as RO was required for some reason.  That is why I went with the harsher sysrq method plus it would reboot no matter what.

Comment: /sbin/reboot isn't working so far.  Looking into why.